# Chat feature in Spring boot connection problem

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am making Web app in spring boot and I want to implement chat inside it, but it does not work. Chat works as standalone app, but inside another app there is problem.
My app is on localhost:8080/
Chat should be on localhost:8080/dopisivanje
Below is my code
Chat model:

```
package com.grupaA.knowledgeSharing.model;
  public class ChatMessage
    {
        private MessageType type;
        private String content;
        private String sender;

        public enum MessageType
        {
            CHAT,
            JOIN,
            LEAVE
        }

        public MessageType getType()
        {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(MessageType type)
        {
            this.type=type;
        }
        public String getContent()
        {
            return content;
        }
        public void setContent(String content)
        {
            this.content=content;
        }
        public String getSender()
        {
            return sender;
        }
        public void setSender(String sender)
        {
            this.sender=sender;
        }
    }
Chat controller

    package com.grupaA.knowledgeSharing.controllers;

import com.grupaA.knowledgeSharing.model.ChatMessage;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;;

@Controller
public class ChatController
{
    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage)
    {
        return chatMessage;
    }
    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor)
    {
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;
    }
    @RequestMapping(path = "/dopisivanje", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String chat()
    {
        return "dopisivanje";
    }
}
```

WebSocketConfig

```
 package config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

WebSocketEventListener:

```
package com.grupaA.knowledgeSharing.controllers;

import com.grupaA.knowledgeSharing.model.ChatMessage;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageSendingOperations;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionConnectedEvent;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionDisconnectEvent;

@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

    //@Autowired
    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messageTemplate;

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event)
    {
        logger.info("Received a new web socket connection");
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event)
    {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

        String username = (String) headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get("username");
        if(username!=null)
        {
            logger.info("User disconnected: " + username);
            ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
            chatMessage.setType(ChatMessage.MessageType.LEAVE);
            chatMessage.setSender(username);

            messageTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

dopisivanje.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat boot</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <h2>Vaš browser ne podržava JavaScript!</h2>
</noscript>
<div id="username-page">
    <div class="username-page-container">
        <h1 class="title">Type your username</h1>
        <form id="usernameForm" name="usernameForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="accent username-submit">Start Chatting</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chat-page" class="hidden">
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-header">
            <h2>Spring WebSocket Chat Demo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="connecting">
            Connecting...
        </div>
        <ul id="messageArea">
        </ul>
        <form id="messageForm" name="messageForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group clearfix">
                    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Unesite poruku..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="primary">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    'use strict';

    var usernamePage = document.querySelector('#username-page');
    var chatPage = document.querySelector('#chat-page');
    var usernameForm = document.querySelector('#usernameForm');
    var messageForm = document.querySelector('#messageForm');
    var messageInput = document.querySelector('#message');
    var messageArea = document.querySelector('#messageArea');
    var connectingElement = document.querySelector('.connecting');

    var stompClient = null;
    var username = null;

    var colors = [
        '#2196F3', '#32c787', '#00BCD4', '#ff5652',
        '#ffc107', '#ff85af', '#FF9800', '#39bbb0'
    ];

    function connect(event) {
        username = document.querySelector('#name').value.trim();

        if(username) {
            usernamePage.classList.add('hidden');
            chatPage.classList.remove('hidden');
            var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

            stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    function onConnected() {
        // Subscribe to the Public Topic
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', onMessageReceived);

        // Tell your username to the server
        stompClient.send("/app/chat.addUser",
            {},
            JSON.stringify({sender: username, type: 'JOIN'})
        )

        connectingElement.classList.add('hidden');
    }


    function onError(error) {
        connectingElement.textContent = 'Could not connect to WebSocket server. Please refresh this page to try again!';
        connectingElement.style.color = 'red';
    }


    function sendMessage(event) {
        var messageContent = messageInput.value.trim();

        if(messageContent && stompClient) {
            var chatMessage = {
                sender: username,
                content: messageInput.value,
                type: 'CHAT'
            };

            stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage", {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage));
            messageInput.value = '';
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    function onMessageReceived(payload) {
        var message = JSON.parse(payload.body);

        var messageElement = document.createElement('li');

        if(message.type === 'JOIN') {
            messageElement.classList.add('event-message');
            message.content = message.sender + ' joined!';
        } else if (message.type === 'LEAVE') {
            messageElement.classList.add('event-message');
            message.content = message.sender + ' left!';
        } else {
            messageElement.classList.add('chat-message');

            var avatarElement = document.createElement('i');
            var avatarText = document.createTextNode(message.sender[0]);
            avatarElement.appendChild(avatarText);
            avatarElement.style['background-color'] = getAvatarColor(message.sender);

            messageElement.appendChild(avatarElement);

            var usernameElement = document.createElement('span');
            var usernameText = document.createTextNode(message.sender);
            usernameElement.appendChild(usernameText);
            messageElement.appendChild(usernameElement);
        }

        var textElement = document.createElement('p');
        var messageText = document.createTextNode(message.content);
        textElement.appendChild(messageText);

        messageElement.appendChild(textElement);

        messageArea.appendChild(messageElement);
        messageArea.scrollTop = messageArea.scrollHeight;
    }


    function getAvatarColor(messageSender)
    {
        var hash = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < messageSender.length; i++)
        {
            hash = 31 * hash + messageSender.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var index = Math.abs(hash % colors.length);
        return colors[index];
    }

    usernameForm.addEventListener('submit', connect, true)
    messageForm.addEventListener('submit', sendMessage, true)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to mention, I am using Spring Security for the whole app, but I did permitAll for dopisivanje.hmtl.
When I start chat and enter username, I became the error:

> Could not connect to WebSocket server. Please refresh this page to try
>   again!
>   In developer console there is:

I am new in JS and Spring, I would be grateful if anyone chat help.

Comment: Can you check if configurations/classes are being scanned by spring? You might be having different java packages

Answer (score 0):

use this in your securityConfig....it worked for me

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)throws Exception{
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/index.html/**", "/css/**", "/js/**","/ws/**");
}
```

Comment: I solved it already. Actually one Java class was in wrong package.